# validation class not calling in system.xml if I defined type image

Tags: magento-2.0, system.xml, system-config

[image]

if I define 'type=file' than validation is calling but image icon is not displaying on screen. but if I define 'type=image' than validations not calling and image icon is displaying on screen. I want to call image validations & want to show image icon on screen using system.xml please let me know if anyone have idea about this.

Comment: add your code here

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

### The problem

Unfortunately the `image` type does not support the validate classes.

First let me explain why it is not working.

When you use the `file` type, the class used to render the field is `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\File.php` and the method that renders every field is `getElementHtml()`.

However, this particular `file` class does not have this method and thus the parent `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php` method is used instead.

This method looks like this:

```
public function getElementHtml()
{
    $html = '';
    $htmlId = $this->getHtmlId();

    if (($beforeElementHtml = $this->getBeforeElementHtml())) {
        $html .= '<label class="addbefore" for="' .
            $htmlId .
            '">' .
            $beforeElementHtml .
            '</label>';
    }

    $html .= '<input id="' .
        $htmlId .
        '" name="' .
        $this->getName() .
        '" ' .
        $this->_getUiId() .
        ' value="' .
        $this->getEscapedValue() .
        '" ' .
        $this->serialize(
            $this->getHtmlAttributes()
        ) . '/>';

    if (($afterElementJs = $this->getAfterElementJs())) {
        $html .= $afterElementJs;
    }

    if (($afterElementHtml = $this->getAfterElementHtml())) {
        $html .= '<label class="addafter" for="' .
            $htmlId .
            '">' .
            $afterElementHtml .
            '</label>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

**The part of the method that adds the validation classes** is:

```
$this->serialize(
    $this->getHtmlAttributes()
)
```

The problem when using the `image` type is that the `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image.php` rewrites the `getElementHtml` like this:

```
public function getElementHtml()
{
    $html = '';

    if ((string)$this->getValue()) {
        $url = $this->_getUrl();

        if (!preg_match("/^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\//", $url)) {
            $url = $this->_urlBuilder->getBaseUrl(['_type' => UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]) . $url;
        }

        $html = '<a href="' .
            $url .
            '"' .
            ' onclick="imagePreview(\'' .
            $this->getHtmlId() .
            '_image\'); return false;" ' .
            $this->_getUiId(
                'link'
            ) .
            '>' .
            '<img src="' .
            $url .
            '" id="' .
            $this->getHtmlId() .
            '_image" title="' .
            $this->getValue() .
            '"' .
            ' alt="' .
            $this->getValue() .
            '" height="22" width="22" class="small-image-preview v-middle"  ' .
            $this->_getUiId() .
            ' />' .
            '</a> ';
    }
    $this->setClass('input-file');
    $html .= parent::getElementHtml();
    $html .= $this->_getDeleteCheckbox();

    return $html;
}
```

**As you can see, this rewritten method does not serialize the HTML attributes that's why no validation class is added.**

### The Solution

Fortunately, I have found that **instead of using an `image` type you can use an `imagefile` type** which is defined under `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Imagefile.php`. Fun point is that this type does not seem to be used anywhere in the Magento default files.

Using this type will add the proper validation class and let you use a proper image upload field.

Comment: top-notch answer....:-) @Raphael

Comment: @Ritika feel free to mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others ;)